# How to change the size of label values in xyplot in R

Tags: r, lattice

I'm using `xyplot` in R to plot several lines (by group) on one graph:

```
xyplot(y~x,
       type=c('l'),
       scales=list(tck=c(1,0)),
       main=list(label="Total decrease", cex=2),
       xlab=list(label="Years", cex=1.5),
       ylab=list(label="Percentage", cex=1.5),
       groups= group,
       data=df,
       auto.key=list(columns=2, lines=TRUE, points=FALSE, cex=1.5))
```

However, I am unable to change the size of the label values. I have tried changing the argument `cex.axis` (within the `xlab` and `ylab` options), but this does not change the size of values along either the x- or the y-axes.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With **lattice** plotting functions, use `scales=list(cex=1.5)` to set `cex` for tick labels along both axes.

To specify different `cex` values for x- and y- axes, do something like this:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(mpg~disp, data=mtcars, 
       scales=list(tck=c(1,0), x=list(cex=1.2), y=list(cex=1.5)))
```

[image]